# In R how do I find whether an integer is divisible by a number?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

Sorry for the inexperience, I'm a beginning coder in R
For example:
If I were to make a FOR loop by chance and I have a collection of integers 1 to 100 (1:100), what would be the proper format to ensure that would print the numbers that are divisible by another number. In this case, 5 being the number divisible. I hear that using modulo would help in this instance %%

This is what I think I should have.

```
For (x in 1:100) {
  x%%5 == y
}
print(y)
```

Comment: `x <- 1:100; x[ x %% 5 == 0 ]` will do. No need for a loop. And in your example, you're not creating `y`, your comparing your result with `y` (and, y  doesn't exist)

Answer (score 16):

```
for (x in 1:100) { 
  if (x%%5 == 0) {
    print(x)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The modulo operator `%%` is used to check for divisibility. Used in the expression
`x %% y`, it will return 0 if `y` is divisible by `x`.

In order to make your code work, you should include an `if` statement to evaluate to `TRUE` or `FALSE` and replace the `y` with `0` inside the curly braces as mentioned above:

```
for (x in 1:100) { 
  if (x%%5 == 0) {
    print(x)
  }
}
```

For a more concise way to check for divisibility consider:

```
for (x in 1:100) { 
  if (!(x%%5)){
    print(x)
  }
}
```

Where `!(x %% 5)` will return `TRUE` for 0 and `FALSE` for non-zero numbers.

Comment: In your text you say `x %% y` will return 0 if `y` is divisible by `x`, but isn't it if `x` is divisible by `y`? For example, `24%%4` will return 0, meaning 24 is divisible by 4, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

How's this?

```
x <- 1:100
div_5 <- function(x) x[x %% 5 == 0]
div_5(x)
```

Comment: This works! And I appreciate the answer. However, I'm struggling to be able to perform the same function using a For Loop, hopefully someone has that answer to this. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i in 1:10) 
{
   if (i %% 2)
   {
      #some code
   }
}
```